# Calculating position of overlapping ovals to create a certain sized center gap

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to solve a problem how to position five circles in longitude and latitude so that four of them overlap so that the fifth one in the middle is exposed by a certain margin.

I drew the diagram below quickly to illustrate what I'm trying to do. Each circle is 10 meters diagonally (or miles, whichever you prefer). The center one is fixed to its position. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the position of four others so that there is approximately 1m2 of the center circle exposed. Essentially the four circles should create a 1m2 rectangle in the middle (obviously it's not an actual rectangle due to the curvature).

The positioning itself isn't that hard but what's throwing me off is how to deal with latitude and longitude where length of a degree is different depending on the coordinates.

All help is appreciated a lot because it's been a long time since I had to work with this type of math, and I can honestly say I'm completely lost :/

[image]

Comment: For ovals, you would need to get the equations, otherwise it's not clear what shapes you are using. Are those circles by any chance? Then, it is not clear how the 1m in the central figure is measured. Is it the shortest distance (vertical or horizontal through the center), the largest distance (diagonally through the center), or something else? Or is it 1m$^2$, the area of that region?

Comment: Heh, I don't know why I used the word ovals and not circles... The 1m central figure is measured as the gap between left & right and top & bottom circles. Essentially you can imagine that there should be a 1m2 box between the four circles. I'm not sure if the central circle is even needed but I figured a fixed center point would make it easier to calculate the positions for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use $(0,0)$ the center of the green circle. To fit a $1m\times 1m$ box in the middle, the distance from that center to any of the circles is $0.5m$. The radius of each of the purple circles is $5m$. So the distance from the origin to each circle is then $5.5m$. Therefore the positions are $(0,5.5)$, $(0,-5.5)$, $(5.5,0)$, and $(-5.5,0)$. The visible area is slightly larger than $1m^2$. If you want to have exactly that area, you need to do an integral.

Comment: I think this correct calculation is just part of what the OP needs. Your origiin $(0,0)$ is at a particular (lat, long) position on the globe. How do degrees convert to meters there? (The figure is small enough so that one conversion factor for each direction will do.)

Comment: @EthanBolker For the given dimensions, you can use planar geometry. Don't need to worry about latitude and longitude on a sphere. But if that's what is really requested, one can use the small angle approximation and divide those numbers by the radius of the Earth, and multiply with $180/\pi$ (to transform to degrees)

Comment: Of course planar geometry works. But a degree of longitude is much longer at the equator than near the poles.

Comment: @EthanBolker is correct, the problem here is calculating the position while taking into account the length of the degree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Length_of_a_degree).

Comment: Assuming that the figure is aligned with the N-S, E-W, then the formula above works for latitude. To account for different lengths in the longitude, instead of radius of the Earth you need to use the radius of the constant latitude circle, which is $R_E\cos(\textrm{latitude})$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Observe that the center of the four circles of radius $r$ form a square. So, it is convenience to place the four circles in terms of the distance $d$ between the adjacent centers.

If the overlapping area of any two circles is $p$, then the exposed area in the middle is

$$A= d^2 - \pi r^2 + 2p$$

It is known that the overlapping area $p$ between two circle of radius $r$ and at a distance $d$ between their centers is given by

$$p = 2r^2\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{d}{2r} \right) - \frac{1}{2}d\sqrt{4r^2-d^2}$$

So, in order to achieve 1$m^2$ for the exposed area, just set up the following equation,

$$1 = d^2 - \pi r^2 + 4r^2\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{d}{2r} \right) - d\sqrt{4r^2-d^2} $$

Given that $r= 5\text{m}$, the distance $d$ among the four circle centers can be solved, albeit maybe numerically.

---

In terms of latitudes and longitudes, assuming the earth radius is $R$ and arbitrary center circle coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$, the right circle is to be placed at

$$\text{latitude}:\>\> \theta; \>\>\>\> \text{longitude}:\>\> \phi + 90^\circ\times \frac{\sqrt{2}d}{\pi R\cos\theta} $$

Similar positions can be derived for other three circles.

Comment: Very interesting solution but how would you take into account the length of degree with latitude and longitude here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Length_of_a_degree)?

Comment: Then, instead of 2d areas, the spherical surface areas have to be considered. The concept is similar; the actual setup is more involved. But, I believe there is little difference if you just talk about miles on earth.